# What is the difference of "maritime" and "marine"?

Tags: word-choice

I know both words have the meaning in relation to sea or ocean, are they interchangeable as in marine corps and maritime organization or marine silk road or is there any rule about using them?

Answer (score 5):

**Maritime** is used most often in connection with seafaring, with sea travel, shipping, and exploration, and aspects of the sea in relation to those activities; whereas **marine** relates directly to the sea and its creatures.

Here's an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maritime%20*%2C%20marine%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmaritime%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmaritime%20power%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20powers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20commerce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20provinces%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20towns%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20affairs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20jurisdiction%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaritime%20nations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cmarine%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmarine%20animals%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20insurance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20shells%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20plants%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20environment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20engines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarine%20organisms%3B%2Cc0). As you can see from the results, while there is no *absolute* demarcation (we find **marine engines** and **marine insurance**, for example) most uses of **marine** relate to the sea environment and its creatures, and most uses of **maritime** relate to seafaring/shipping/commerce, their activities, and the places associated with them.